# How to write in flask a function that is able to treat arbitrary requests?

Tags: python, url, web, flask

I have the following function that returns the path of the page that is loaded. For example, if I load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/aaa` I get `aaa` (as expected and desired).

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<path:path>")
def default(path):
    return path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, if I load `http://127.0.0.1:5000` I get `Not Found` error. It can be explained by the fact that in the pattern that I use I have slash and I do not have slash in the request.

But there are two things that I do not understand:

1. Why I cannot remove slash from the pattern (from `/<path:path>`). My expectation was the following: if I use `route("<path:path>")` and then load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/aaa`, I should get `\aaa` instead of `aaa`. But instead of that, flask refuses to work.
2. If I use slash in the route (i.e. `@app.route("/<path:path>")`) and then load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` (note the slash in the end). I expect to get an empty string as a result. But instead flask refuses to work again.

So, how can I write a function that is able to accept arbitrary path including the empty path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change little bit in your code

```
@app.route("/<path>")
def default(path=None):
    return path
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the slash from the pattern because [it's required](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/9c93b11485d5714dfbd1c338c71660cbc2f2e70b/werkzeug/routing.py#L540-L541) by Werkzeug's routing.

There is a [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/) that should address this exact scenario, having a catch all endpoint. To summarize it,  you will need to include an additional route for `default`:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
```